# How to convert jupyterbook to pdf

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyterbook

I have a folder for jupyter bookdown that I want to convert to PDF. This book is composed of many .MDs. How to convert ths?

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is converting it to an HTML and then after opening that you can print it to a pdf using your browser, like so.

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html my_file.ipynb
```

and then after opening the new html file in your browser you can choose to print as a pdf.
Make sure you open a terminal in the same directory where your notebook is saved and then run the command